# How to fix "Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY)"

Tags: cocos2d-x

It appears you are building natively for Linux with GCC

```
Cocos2dx on Linux : "cmake -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles'
-- OpenGL include dirs: /usr/include
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:44 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosBuildHelpers.cmake:44 (find_package)
  cocos2d/CMakeLists.txt:190 (cocos_find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/daw/Dev/cocos2d-x-3.9/allProject/testC/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: make sure you have installed all the dependencies listed in http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Linux_Installation_and_Setup

Answer (score 20):

It's quite an old question but I was looking for solution of the same issue and came here, so maybe my answer will help someone in future.

In Ubuntu 17.10 it was enough to install libglew-dev package to solve this

```
sudo apt install libglew-dev
```

Answer (score 8):

Download [The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) and add include and lib path in cmake project file.

For example:

```
set(GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR, "/glew-2.0.0/include/")
set(GLEW_LIBRARY, "/glew-2.0.0/lib")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to remove the commas after the variable names.

Comment: im still getting the error and i did all the steps listed above

Answer (score 1):

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "path/to/glew")

add this in the relevant CMakeLists.txt

for details see this link https://itecnote.com/tecnote/cmake-cant-find-glew/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).